# Databinder.eval not working with (e.Row.DataItem, "var.var")

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working on an asp webforms page. I fill the columns and rows of a gridview dynamically, and with the rowDataBound event get the sum for each row and column.  and it works fine, except if the column has a name like "EN.DESARROLLO".
it seems that the Databinder.eval doesn't work if it have a '.' in the column name.
is there other way to get the value? or use databinder.eval in some other way? 
here is my code:

```
private int[] totales = new int[100];
protected void grdTecnicos_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    List<diccListaString> estados = getEstadosAbiertos();

    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < estados.Count() + 2; i++)
            {
                BoundField field = (BoundField)((DataControlFieldCell)e.Row.Cells[i]).ContainingField;
                if (field.HeaderText == "TOTAL")
                {
                    int ac = totales[i - 1];
                    int n = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TOTAL"));
                    int t = ac + n;
                    totales[i - 1] = t;
                }
                else if (i < estados.Count())
                {
                    int ac = totales[i];
                    int n = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, estados[i].Descripcion));// here is the problem

                    int t = ac + n;
                    totales[i] = t;
                }

            }
        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= estados.Count() + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "TOTAL:";
                else
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Text = totales[i - 1].ToString();
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        mostrar_error(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "EN.DESARROLLO") %>
```

Or

```
<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["EN.DESARROLLO"] %>
```